# Will Lambda send events to EventBridge when a function is started and finished?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I would like EventBridge to be notified when any Lambda function starts and finishes execution.

I am NOT trying to trigger the Lambda functions from EventBridge.

I do NOT want to modify my Lambda function code to write custom events to EventBridge.

What I'm hoping for is some way to create a rule in EventBridge that will be triggered whenever any Lambda function in my account is started or finished. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudwatch rule based on [event patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html) is not supported for AWS Lambda as of now (2023-11-02)

This is supported for various services like [codebuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html)

We need to add a custom rule for this use case if we need to do that task.

Answer (score 1):

What might work is to use CloudTrail (see Using CloudTrail to track function invocations https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) and filter for those events in EventBridge.

Comment: Interesting idea,  it it doesn’t look like the Invoke API call is one of the ones that CloudTrail captures. Even if it did, that would give me a start notification but not a stop.